# Dekker Mutual-Exclusion

Tags: multithreading, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++, operating-system

I'm studying the operating system and the program that Dekker wrote for his third attempt to Mutual Exclusion
I wrote my code in C ++ in Visual Studio, the code is below, but I wonder how these two threads are still in the critical area at the same time?
The output of the program is below

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

bool flag0 = false;
bool flag1 = false;

void p1()
{
    flag0 = true;
    while (flag1);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        cout << "p1 : " << i << endl;
    flag0 = false;

}

void p2()
{
    flag1 = true;
    while (flag0);
    for (int i = -1; i >= -10; i--)
        cout << "p2 : " << i << endl;
    flag1 = false;
}

int main()
{

    thread t1(p1);
    thread t2(p2);


    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
p1 : p2 : -11

p2 : p1 : 2
p1 : 3
p1 : 4
p1 : 5
p1 : 6
-2
p2 : -3
p2 : -4
p2 : -5
p2 : -6
p2 : -7
p2 : -8
p2 : -9
p2 : p1 : -107
p1 : 8
p1 : 9
p1 : 10
```

Comment: A boolean variable is not a critical section, use std::mutex instead

Comment: @Equod  I know how to use mutex.
My problem is how it is possible that when one of the flags is true, the second thread enters the critical section again and executes the for loop and doesn't care to the while condition?

Comment: There is no critical section here. "while (flag1)" and "while (flag0)" are executed once on different threads and ensure that the other thread is already started. Then both threads print stuff in for loops.

Comment: @Equod there is no need for a mutex! The whole point of the Dekker algorithm is to achieve mutual exclusion for two threads using only load and store operations. However, since this is only the third attempt and not the final (correct) version, it _does_ provide mutual exclusion (under a sequentially consistent memory model), but is prone to deadlocks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your flags are ordinary `bool` variables, which results in a data race and therefore UB. That basically means that all bets are off about how your program behaves! For example, the compiler could hoist the load in the while-loop, effectively transforming the loop into an infinite loop. But infinite loops without side effects are also UB, so the compiler is well in its right to remove the loop entirely!

But even if the compiler does not perform these optimizations, the code still does not guarantee mutual exclusion, because the flag operations are not sequentially consistent. Essentially what can happen is that both threads store `true` in their respective flag, but it is not guaranteed that this updated value is visible to the other thread. So it can happen that the subsequent load operations in the while-loop still return false *for both threads*.

To get the desired behavior, the operations on the flags need to be *sequentially consistent*, which means that all such operations have a *single total order*. To achieve that you have to define your flags as `std::atomic<bool>`. All operations on atomics are sequentially consistent by default (unless specified otherwise).

However, since this is the third attempt by Dekker and not the final (correct) version, it does provide mutual exclusion (under a sequentially consistent memory model), but is prone to deadlocks!

For more details you should familiarize yourself with the C++ memory model. I can recommend the paper [Memory Models for C/C++ Programmers](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04432) which I have co-authored.

Comment: (Not my downvote). The first sentence is correct, but the point of UB is that there's little you can say with certainty about what happens afterwards. You talk about a "load operation in a while loop", but there's probably no such thing here. Any half-decent optimizer can hoist that load out of the while-loop, remove the empty loop and discard the unused load. The second paragraph recovers, but it might be useful to add that it's talking about the desired behavior _in Dekker's algorithm_.

Comment: @MSalters You are absolutely right that since the data race results in UB, all bets are off about what happens afterward. I wanted to explain how this can go wrong in a non-sequentially consistent memory model, but did not consider other possible optimizations. Thanks for the note, I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

" I wonder how these two threads are still in the critical area at the same time"

You've got two threads accessing the same variables, without any form of synchronization. In C++, that is a form of Undefined Behavior. Undefined Behavior means that anything can happen. "Two threads in the same critical area at the same time" is not even remotely surprising.

Comment: Honestly, I did not understand your answer correctly (maybe because I'm new in this topic) or maybe I did not ask my questions correctly.
If in the first thread in function p1, flag0 change to true
and just after that flag1 pass the while loop condition (because it's false), then assume it switches to the second thread, now it's impossible that the flag0 pass the while loop condition(because flag0 is true now) 
that's true that this code can have deadlock but this output surprised me!!

Comment: I'll be happy for you to introduce resources in this field so that I can read

Comment: @dariushstory: the "switch to other thread" logic does not work like that. Logically, both threads run at the same time, and you need synchronization so that variables shared between them have a consistent state.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<thread>
using namespace std;

bool turnop1 = false;

void p1()
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        while (turnop1 == false);
        cout << "p1 : " << i << endl;
        turnop1 = false;
    }
}

void p2()
{
    for (int t = -1; t >= -10; t--)
    {
        while (turnop1 == true);
        cout << "p2 : " << t << endl;
        turnop1 = true;
    }
}


int main()
{

    thread t1(p1);
    thread t2(p2);


    t2.join();
    t1.join();

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Modified your code and worked for me. Thanks! I know this is not completely right but this Dekker's idea/example is enough for a simple explanation.